# Using Google Mobile Vision API on Android Things

Tags: android-things

I'm trying to use Google Mobile Vision API on Android Things but apparently, it depends on Play Store as described by this stacktrace:

```
05-24 06:17:26.714 4993-4993/com.ee.foo 
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
Error creating remote native face detector
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local 
version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

I know Play Store wouldn't be available for Android Things but is there a way of doing this or I should just use Cloud Vision API instead?

Comment: Interesting! Did you connect your Android things board to the internet and reboot it at least once? (I'm wondering if it needs to download this apk dependency) i.e. the user facing playstore isn't available but the backing tech (that updates google play services) should be

Comment: Yeah it's connected to the internet and I declared the dependency in my gradle file. I will try rebooting the device and see if that makes any difference. I've got a working solution now but it's using Cloud Vision API which is fine but it would be perfect if it can be done locally

Comment: Did you find a local solution in the end? I think I am running into similar issues as you @MarcTan.

Comment: @JamesBritton I recently updated my project and now I'm using Google ML Kit. And yes, the smile detection which is what I needed before works perfectly offline.